# google.maps.Polygon vs google.maps.Data.Polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Looking at the documentation on Google's Api site (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-polygon  |   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-hole) in reference to the two polygon types, I'm not really seeing a difference between the two but, I'm sure i may be overlooking something.

Is there a difference between the google.maps.Polygon and the  google.maps.Data.Polygon?

I'm interested in using the api to draw a series of clickable polygons on the map. Which one is best practices to meet this need?

Comment: If they need to be clickable I'd say go with the `google.maps.Polygon` class. The Data class lets you have event listeners, but I think the standard Polygon will give you more flexibility.

Comment: Are you going to use a [DataLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) ?

Comment: duncan,Yes, they will need to be clickable.

Comment: geocodezip, 
I may use a datalayer as I will need to display other content along with the shapes such as points and polylines.